# Infinite loop reading a text file

Tags: php, wordpress, php-parse-error

I am making a custom theme in WordPress. Now inside the theme folder is another folder named "php" with a text file in it, let's say "names.txt". Now what I want to do is read the text file from the "php" folder. I have this codes in my index.php:

```
<?php

 $file = fopen("/php/names.txt","r");

 while(! feof($file))
 {
 echo fgets($file). "<br />";
 }

 fclose($file);

 ?>
```

But my webpage is stuck in infinite loop, with errors that the file doesn't exists though it does. Badly need help.
UPDATE: I tried running the codes above in a separate php.file which I placed in the same directory with the "names.txt" file, and it reads the data.

UPDATE [SOLVED]:

```
<?php

$location = get_template_directory() . "/php/admin.txt";
if ( file_exists( $location )) {
$file = fopen($location, "r");

while(!feof( $file )) {
    echo fgets($file). "<br />";
} 

fclose($file);
}
else
{echo "no file.";}
?>
```

Works like magic, thanks to @MackieeE

Comment: Try adding a blank line to the end of your 'names.txt' file

Comment: the data inside the 'names.txt' file? or like this:
$file = fopen("/php/names.txt_","r");

Comment: Open your names.txt file and add a blank line at the end/bottom of it.

Comment: Is your file really in a php directory under the filesystem root, or under the webserver's DocumentRoot directory?

Comment: 'names.txt' is located here "C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\euro\php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start off by doing a better check system for the file, using [`file_exists()`](http://www.php.net/file_exists):

```
if ( !file_exists( "/php/names.txt", "r" )) 
   echo "File not found";
```

Then let's look on how you're calling the file *from* - it's probably just unable to find it! Currently, your WordPress script is probably calling it from the themes folder as below:

```
   --> root
      --> wp-content
        --> themes
          --> yourtheme
            --> php
              --> names.txt
```

Although as mentioned, the *current* script is looking for it in:

```
  --> root
    --> php
      --> names.txt
```

Because of the *starting* slash within your `/php/`

Make sure you're placing your names.txt in the correct location, you can use Wordpress'es pre-defined variables [`get_template_directory()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory) or PHP's `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` to make sure you point to the correct folder if need be:

```
 $location = get_template_directory() . "php/names.txt";
 if ( file_exists( $location )) {
    $file = fopen($location, "r");

    while(!feof( $file )) {
        echo fgets($file). "<br />";
    } 

    fclose($file);
 }
```

Comment: it returns no file found in directory. The problem is it does not get inside the php folder, it only checks until "C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\euro\" instead of "C:\wamp\www\wordpress\wp-content\themes\euro\php"

Comment: Well does it in that case work if you moved `names.txt` into the `/euro/` folder?

Comment: it returns the same @MackieeE, no file found but it does really exist I am sure of it. I have noticed that wordpress has specific functions in using javascript and jquery, maybe there is also a special function to read a .txt file.

Comment: thanks for editing, get_template_directory() does the trick. :-)